# Spacy 3.8 numpy.ufunc size changed may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, spacy

I switched from Windows development to Ubuntu 19.04 and after installing my libaries using pip I got the runtime warning about numpy.ufunc size changed.

I am using the following versions and my project is in PyCharm Professional (lastest version).

Spacy 2.1.8
numpy 1.17.2
blis 0.4.0
thinc 7.0.8
gensim 2.8

I have uninstalled everything and installed SPACY last, I have uninstalled numpy and put version 1.15 up and various other tricks but I can't see to get it to install the correct version.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or which actual version of numpy/thinc/blis should be used in this case?

Comment: Could you post the full error message? Also, are you using a Virtual Environment?